# Java Square Class

Tags: java

Here is what I am asked to do:
1.  Create a class called Square that takes a width parameter in the constructor.  The Square class should have a draw() method that will draw the square on the screen.  Create a class called TestSquare that will take width from the user, create an object of Square, and invoke the draw() method on the square object.

Here is what I have, but the problem I am having is passing the draw() method to the test method. I know see that I need to move the for loops from the test to the class, so that i can call it in the test main method.

```
public class Square {
    /** the width of square*/
    int width;

    /** construct the square*/
    Square(){   
    }

    /**construct a square */
    Square(int newWidth){
        width = newWidth;
}

/**show the square*/
  void draw(){
  for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
  {
   for (int j=0; j<width; j++)
   {    System.out.print("* ");}

   System.out.println();
  }

}
}
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestSquare {
  /** Main method */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Create a scanner input
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

  // prompt user to enter width
System.out.println("Creating a Square ...");
    System.out.print("Please enter its width:");
    int width = input.nextInt();


   Square square = new Square(width);
   System.out.println("Here is the Square:"); 
   square.draw();



  }

}
```

Comment: _it doesn't seem to pass correctly_: Use a debugger.

Comment: So, uh, can you explain what's going on here? - `int getWidth() { return width*width; }`

Comment: What exactly is the question? It's impossible to help you get it to "pass correctly" without knowing exactly what output you expect. Can you provide a sample of the output from this program, and also a sample of what output you expected? You may also find Eric Lippert's blog post [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) useful.

Comment: i need to be able to using the TestSquare, have it run the Square.java. So that I can enter a width of a square when prompt and it will then draw the square. so for a width of 4 show 4 rows of 4 *'s

Comment: For starters, it doesn't look like you've even defined or used a draw() method on your Square object. But your description of your homework assignment says this is a requirement. There are other issues as well.

Comment: @planker1010: Did you read that "How to debug small programs" link? I can help you debug, but *teaching* you how to debug is probably more valuable. There are half a dozen things wrong with this code -- you'll need to break it down into pieces and fix each one.

Comment: @Charlie yes the problem is the book doesn't go over the Draw() method. in the chapter that I am on. It only goes over drawing in the GUI 5 chapters later.

Comment: @DanielPryden yes I have started reading the link. However I only see 1 possible compiler error that it shows using eclipse. Also I seem to be lacking a "Draw() method" which my book doesn't speak of. And I can only find reference to it about GUI.

Comment: @DanielPryden thanks for the link to the debugging, I was able to use it to help, I will be able to now moving forward post better requests for help that will be more concise.

Comment: I have edited this, I have also found the resolution to this issue.

Comment: After editing it makes less sense than it did before. `draw width()` isn't even going to compile.

Comment: @DavidMoles Sorry I forgot to update with the correct code. Here is what I have that now works according to the assignment request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop into this:

```
for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
{
   for (int j=0; j<width; j++)
   { System.out.print("*"); }

   System.out.println();
}
```

As said, remove semicolons after loops because this makes your loop end immediately without arguments. i should be set to 1 so that it would reiterate in the correct number of times

And edit your getWidth() method into this:

```
int getWidth() {
    return width;
}
```

Using width*width would make the method return n^2 of the width. It's supposed to be width not area.

Edit: I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do but try putting this inside Square class:

```
void draw() {
    for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
{
   for (int j=0; j<width; j++)
   { System.out.print("*"); }

   System.out.println();
}
}
```

Remove the getWidth() method completely. Then replace your getWidth() invocation with this:

```
square.draw();
```

Comment: I have done that. However I do not believe that Is what truley needs to happen for me to call the Square Class and get it to draw it based upon the input from the user for the width. If I go back to the class and change the int getWidth(){ return (width*2); it does not take my width input and times by 2. So I feel that the test is not pulling for the class Square for some reason.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to implement. Are you supposed to construct the "*" without loops?

Comment: I need to invoke a draw()method to get it to draw the square after I take the users input for the width

Comment: Then you shouldn't need the getWidth() method anymore. Just invoke draw and put the for loop inside it

Comment: Thanks, thats the piece I was missing, i was trying to put the for loop into the test not into the class. Now I am able to call the draw() from the class. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems.

Either rename this method to "getArea" or return width only:

```
int getWidth() {
    return width*width;
}
```

Do not put a semicolon at the end of the for loop declarations. That makes the for loop do nothing. Also, the outer for loop should start at 0 (not 1):

```
for (int i=1; i<width; i++);  //remove this trailing semicolon
{
   for (int j=0; j<width; j++); //remove this trailing semicolon
       System.out.print("*");
   System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: and the line `square.getWidth();` by itself does nothing.